# Need clarification about Lambdas, auto and decltype in SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, sfinae, auto

I have been trying to learn about SFINAE tricks by reading the following article [Link](https://jguegant.github.io/blogs/tech/sfinae-introduction.html), but having trouble in understanding some parts of it.

Full code: [Link](https://gist.github.com/Jiwan/7a586c739a30dd90d259)

I am confused mostly about these lines of code.

```
// Check if a type has a serialize method.
auto hasSerialize = is_valid([](auto&& x) 
    -> decltype(x.serialize()) { });

template <class T> auto serialize(T& obj) 
    -> typename std::enable_if<decltype(hasSerialize(obj))::value, std::string>::type
{
    return obj.serialize();
}

template <class T> auto serialize(T& obj) 
    -> typename std::enable_if<!decltype(hasSerialize(obj))::value, std::string>::type
{
    return to_string(obj);
}
```

Especially with hasSerialize line and it's use in decltype with an argument. Can anyone tell me what is happing here ? Is hasSerialize is a method ? What is the expression(lambda) to the right side of hasSerialize will evaluates to actually ? What is the order of execution in the evaluation ? What does auto evaluates to in hasSeriaize ?

Please help me to understand this as I am struggling with this for a week, but still can't my head around it. Would appreciate if any one can give an practical example of this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this code is using [`boost::hana::is_valid`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1type.html#a2d2e7e08e284f7e0bd1bd9c3ad0e0a2b) - make sure to read its documentation and understand what it is doing.

---

> Is hasSerialize is a method?

No, it is a variable initialized with a lambda expression. It is a [closure](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

---

> What is the expression(lambda) to the right side of hasSerialize will evaluates to actually ?

The following code...

```
auto hasSerialize = is_valid([](auto&& x) -> decltype(x.serialize()) { });
```

...will create a *function object* that when invoked with an object `y` will return `std::true_type` if `y.serialize()` is a valid expression, `std::false_type` otherwise. Example:

```
struct Foo { };
struct Bar { void serialize() { } };

static_assert(!hasSerialize(std::declval<Foo>()));
static_assert(hasSerialize(std::declval<Bar>()));
```

Here's a simple possible implementation of `is_valid`:

```
template <typename TF>
struct validity_checker
{
    template <typename... Ts>
    constexpr auto operator()(Ts... ts)
    {
        return std::is_callable<
            TF(typename decltype(ts)::type...)
        >{};
    }
};

template <typename TF>
constexpr auto is_valid(TF)
{
    return validity_checker<TF>{};
}
```

It simply uses [`std::is_callable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_callable) to see if the *generic lambda* with a trailing `decltype` can be called with some particular arguments. **If the expression inside the trailing `decltype` is not valid for some particular argument types, the lambda is not callable.**

---

`is_callable` can be implemented in a SFINAE-friendly way as follows, using `void_t`:

```
template <typename...>
using void_t = void;

template <typename, typename = void>
struct is_callable : std::false_type { };

template <typename TF, class... Ts>
struct is_callable<TF(Ts...),
    void_t<decltype(std::declval<TF>()(std::declval<Ts>()...))>>
    : std::true_type { };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will go though your answer and see if this clears by reading more about lamdas(closure as I still did not get it from your link). Will get back to you in a day.